# Sort data using conditional relationship

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, relationship, eloquent-relationship

I want to create a scope 'sortByName' for the Contact model

I have three tables

1. contacts table:

   `id | type | state  | is_for_promotion | is_important`

now **type** can either contain **INDIVIDUAL** or **ORGANIZATIONAL**

If the type is ORGANIZATIONAL sort should happen by name in organization table.

Else if the type is INDIVIDUAL sort should happen by concatenation of first_name and last_name in contact_individual_details table

2. contact_organizational_details table:

   `id | contact_id | name`
3. contact_individual_details table:

   `id | contact_id | first_name | last_name`

and following relationships in Contact model

```
    public function individualDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ContactIndividualDetails::class);
    }

    public function organizationalDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ContactOrganizationalDetails::class);
    }
```

I want to create a scope such as Contact::sortByName()->get().
But I'm not able to think about the body of the scope.

Comment: You want to sort by the name column in the organization table?

Comment: Either name in organization table. Or by concatenation of f_name and l_name if type is INDIVIDUAL